# Dynamic image source binding in silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, binding, ivalueconverter

I want to set an image's source according to its `DataContext` in a `ChildWindow`. Here is the XAML file:

```
<controls:ChildWindow x:Class="CEM.Controls.DialogWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
           xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls" Title="{Binding Title}">
  ...
  <Image x:Name="DialogIcon"></Image>
  ...
</controls:ChildWindow>
```

It's working fine if I override the `Show` method of the `ChildWindow` and set the image's source:

```
public new void Show()
{
    DialogIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/DialogWindow/Confirm.png", UriKind.Relative));
    base.Show();
}
```

But it looks ugly and it's not the "silverlight way", so I decide to change:

```
<Image x:Name="DialogIcon" Source="{Binding DialogIconType, Converter={StaticResource DialogIconConverter}}"></Image>
```

You see I have a `DialogIconConverter` registered to bind the source from the `DataContext`.

```
public class DialogIconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       //currently it's an hard-coded path
       return new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/DialogWindow/Confirm.png", UriKind.Relative));
    }
    ...
 }
```

But it's not working now, I have several other converters in this control which are working fine. Only this one is not working. Can you help to find where the problem is?

EDIT: `DialogIconType` is an enum, and also it's a property of `DialogContext`. An instance of `DialogContext` will be assigned to `DataContext` property of the `DialogWindow`.

```
public enum DialogIconType
{ 
    Confirm,
    Alert,
    Error
}
public class DialogContext
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DialogButtons Buttons { get; set; }
    public DialogIconType IconType { get; set; }
}
internal DialogWindow(DialogContext context)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = context;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using "Images/DialogWindow/Confirm.png" instead of "/Images/DialogWindow/Confirm.png"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

might be silly, but did you make sure that your converter is referenced properly in your xaml file ?

otherwise, I suggest trying this syntax as path for your URI (with images setup as resources):

```
return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/DialogWindow/Confirm.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

**EDIT :**

ok, I think I've got it :
look into your output window, you will probably see some error 40 binding ... blablabla...

My guess is that the converter is right, but the source of the binding isn't, so basically the converter is not even used.

The reason is that your DialogIconType is not a dependency property, so it cannot be bound to.

in other words, this :

```
public DialogIconType IconType { get; set; }
```

should become this :

```
public static DependencyProperty IconTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IconType", typeof(DialogIconType), typeof(DialogContext));
public DialogIconType IconType
{
    get { return (DialogIconType)(GetValue(IconTypeProperty)); }
    set { SetValue(IconTypeProperty , value); }
}
```

**plus, in your Xaml, you should Bind to "IconType", and not "DialogIconType" (which is a type and not a property)**

(this might even be the sole issue, as I'm not sure if a dependencyProperty Is actually realy needed here, now that I think of it)

Comment: It's correctly referenced in `App.xaml`,some other converters are there with it.

Comment: @Danny: I edited with some reflexion I had regarding you problem

Comment: It's a typo! I need to change `DialogIconType` to `IconType`! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `DialogIconType` is the path to your image (e.g. "Images/DialogWindow/Confirm.png"), it should work without a valueconverter as shown below:

```
<Image Source="{Binding DialogIconType}" />
```

**EDIT:**

Returning the path to the image from the valueconverter's `Convert` method is also possible - i.e.:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return "Images/DialogWindow/Confirm.png";
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

The following also works using `UriKind.Relative`:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/DialogWindow/Confirm.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: @Jakob: Not working. Because the `Source` property of an `Image` is `ImageSource` type, not a `string` type. We can assign a string value in XAML to the `Source` property because it will then be converted to `ImageSource` since there is a `DependencyProperty` named `SourceProperty` in `Image` class. But if you implement your own `Converter`, you must return the exact type.

Comment: @Danny Chen: Hmm... works for me.  What version of Silverlight are you using?

Comment: @Jakob: SL4. I think the issue is not because of "/" since it's working when I put it in `Show()` method.

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors in the Output windows when running debug?

Comment: @Danny Chen: Sorry, can't help you with Prism.  Sounds like your project might be messed up though.  The valueconverter works perfectly for me.